# In python sockets will a output buffer solve my resource error?

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

i keep getting this error uncaptured python exception, closing channel <**main**.Handler connected 94.173.149.187:51162 at 0x2ac3dbeb48c0> (socket.error:(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable').

I read that is problem is caused because im trying to send data whilst data is still sending. First is this true ? it sounds possible and second is there some kind of output buffer i can use or is there a way to detect if python is sending so i can wait ?

Also does it make any differnt that im running two asyncore servers in two different threads ?

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this problem by doing :

```
socket.setblocking(0)
```

see the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) for why , hope this can help :)

Comment: @kizzie33: when you have this error when you do a send() or a recv() ??? it's very important to know, because if this error happen in socket.send() my answer should definitely work, if not you can use socket.sendall() and if it's happening when you do a socket.recv() so this error mean that you have tried to read an empty buffer which shouldn't bother you can just put it in a try execpt or check why you can a socket.recv() while nothing was send and try to remove the call of recv() , hope this can help :)